# Detecting user's platform

Tags: php, android, ios, css, html

I would like to be able to detect a user's platform and load content based on whether the user is using a mobile phone or computer to view the site.

Preferably I'd like to use a php include() to load a full page based on the conditions above. CSS would be next although I'd prefer php because I also want the content to be a bit different for the mobile version.

I basically need to serve up 2 versions of the site:

1. For regular computer
2. For cell phone browsers

Is this doable or am I going down a dead end road.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: look at a responsive framework like skeleton

Comment: What do you mean by 'platform'? Because it isn't possible to detect OS in CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt - Still hoping for a PHP solution as this doesn't address my content difference problem...

Comment: Hello Pavlo - Sorry, not the best way of expressing myself. What I meant was I would like to find out if the user is using mobile browsing and serve up a different page (not just CSS-wise). Is this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to detect the  contents of the User-Agent. Use an array of the mobile agents to identify your 'if mobile statement'.

Comment: Thank you - :) Now I know where to look... much appreciated.